# Adding "text-block" to \sbBloc

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm all new to TiKz and the schemabloc package. What I'd like to know is two things; (1) how to add a "text-block" to a \sbBloc like in the image below (this is the image I'm trying to copy) and (2) how do I draw the T_d(s) signal in schemabloc? Thanks in advance!

[image]

My code is here:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}

% ------- Enable UTF8 characters ------- %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% ------- Page layout ------- %
\usepackage{fullpage}
\headsep = 24pt % spacing between header and text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \rightmark} % section
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark} % chapter
\fancyhead[LO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{blindtext} % lorem ipsum replica
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{framed}




% ------- Math ------- %
\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}  % bold math characters
\usepackage{icomma}                         % use , as decimal pointer
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,amsmath}
\MakeRobust{\eqref}


%-------  Coding ------- %
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    frame               = false,
    language            = C++,
    aboveskip           = 3mm,
    belowskip           = 3mm,
    showstringspaces    = false,
    columns             = flexible,
    basicstyle          = {\small\ttfamily},
    numbers             = left,
    numberstyle         = \tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle        = \color{blue},
    commentstyle        = \color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle         = \color{mauve},
    breaklines          = true,
    breakatwhitespace   = true,
    tabsize             = 3,
    moredelim           = **[is][\color{mauve}]{@}{@},
}
\lstdefinelanguage{VHDL}{
  morekeywords={
    abs,access,after,alias,all,and,architecture,array,assert,attribute,
    begin,block,body,buffer,bus,
    case,component,configuration,constant,
    disconnect,downto,
    else,elsif,end,entity,exit,
    file,for,function,generate,generic,generic,
    if,impure,in,inertial,inout,is,
    label,library,linkage,literal,loop,
    map,mod,
    nand,new,next,nor,not,null,
    of,on,open,or,others,out,
    package,port,postponed,procedure,process,pure,
    range,record,register,reject,rem,report,return,rol,ror,
    select,severity,shared,shared,sla,sll,sra,srl,subtype,
    then,to,transport,type,
    unaffected,units,until,use,
    variable,
    wait,when,while,with,
    xnor,xor
  },
  morekeywords={rising_edge,falling_edge},
  sensitive=false,
  morecomment=[l]--
}
\lstdefinestyle{vhdl}{
  language     = VHDL,
  basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue}\bfseries,
  commentstyle = \color{dkgreen}
}
\lstset{
    emph={falling_edge,rising_edge,std_logic_vector,std_logic}, emphstyle=\color{mauve}
}


%\lstinline|•|
%\begin{lstlisting}
%\lstin­put­list­ing{file­name.c}



% ------- Images ------- %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{gray}{\color{gray}\hypersetup{linkcolor=gray}}
\captionsetup{
    textfont={footnotesize,sc,gray},
    font={footnotesize,sc,gray},
    %linkcolor={footnotesize,sc,gray},
}
\usepackage{booktabs}


% ------- Tikz ------- %
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usepackage{verbatim}


% ------- Colors ------- %
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}


% ------- Links -------- %
\usepackage{hyperref} % clickable references
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


% ------- Debug ------- %
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \sbEntree{E}
    \sbComp*{a}{E}
    \sbBloc{pacemaker}{$\frac{K}{\frac{1}{12}s+1}$}{a}
        \sbRelier[]{E}{a}
        \sbRelier[]{a}{pacemaker}
    \sbSumh*{c}{pacemaker}
        \sbRelier[]{pacemaker}{c}
    \sbBloc{heart}{$\frac{1}{s}$}{c}
        \sbRelier[]{c}{heart}
    \sbSortie{S}{heart}
        \sbRelier[]{heart}{S}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{S}{U}
        \sbBlocr{sensor}{$K_m=1$}{U}
\sbRelieryx{heart-S}{sensor}
\sbRelierxy[]{sensor}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question, I used `rectangle split` for the node style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \sbStyleBloc{rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,align=center}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbComp*{a}{E}
    \sbBloc{pacemaker}{Pacemaker \nodepart{second} $\dfrac K{\frac1{12}s+1}$}{a}
        \sbRelier[]{E}{a}
        \sbRelier[]{a}{pacemaker}
    \sbSumh*[5]{c}{pacemaker}
        \sbRelier[]{pacemaker}{c}
    \sbBloc{heart}{Heart \nodepart{second} $\dfrac1s$}{c}
        \sbRelier[]{c}{heart}
    \sbSortie{S}{heart}
        \sbRelier[]{heart}{S}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[6]{S}{U}
        \sbBlocr{sensor}{Rate measurement \\ sensor \nodepart{second} $K_m=1$}{U}
\sbRelieryx{heart-S}{sensor}
\sbRelierxy[]{sensor}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup for question 2, you can use `\draw[<-,>=stealth] (c) -- ++(0,1.25) node[above] {$T_{d}(s)$};` just before `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, this works perfectly. Thanks guys!